# java zoneddatetime: keep timezone ID when doing calculations

Tags: java, datetime, groovy, elasticsearch-painless, zoneddatetime

I have some small scripting-code in painless (a Groovy dialect, which itself is based on Java) that parses some timestamps with a zone-id.
However, when doing calculations that involve crossing over a daylight-saving-time-boundary, the timezone-id is changed.

Reproducible example:

```
def form=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss (zzz)")
in=ZonedDateTime.parse(input, form)
out_plusweek=in.plusHours(168).format(form)
```

For most inputs I work with the result is fine:
`2019-08-27 11:05:00 (Europe/Amsterdam)` gives `2019-09-03 11:05:00 (Europe/Amsterdam)`, identical for similar dates.

However, if I input `2019-03-29 11:05:00 (Europe/Amsterdam)`, the out-variable is set to `2019-04-05 12:05:00 (CEST)`.

The value itself is fine, but the timezone-designation is changed to `CEST` (Central European Summer Time). It's correct, but no longer parseable by the next step in my script, which needs an id like `Europe/Amsterdam`

So how can I get `2019-04-05 12:05:00 (Europe/Amsterdam)`?

Comment: @Abra Yes, `VV` was what I needed, thanks! And you're right, it's not strictly java. It's painless (used by elasticsearch), which is a Groovy dialect as I understand it (I have no experience with Groovy itself).

Comment: @Abra And if you care about it: I'll accept your answer if you make it into one

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a different format pattern for printing out the result. Try using `VV` instead of `zzz`.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) lowercase `z` will give you the time zone name such as Pacific Standard Time or PST. For the time zone ID such as America/Los_Angeles you need uppercase `V`. And:

> If the count of letters is two, then the time-zone ID is output. Any
>   other count of letters throws `IllegalArgumentException`.